# how to schedule kafka topic message consumptions?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, scheduling, scheduler, kafka-consumer-api

I've been working with `Apache Kafka` and was able to publish and consume messages on my `Ubuntu` server. So basically I've got my publisher Java program & on the other hand I've got my consumer Java program.

I'm hereby providing the source code for my Consumer [class](http://pastebin.com/ZzNJkcT1). I've got somewhat knowledge on `scheduling` such as `Threads` and `TimerTask`. In the source code I'm printing the messages repetitively using a while.

What I want to know is, how could I print, the number of messages (ie: count of the messages) have been consumed within a period of 3 seconds. I've done something like this when I'm publishing the messages:.

```
TimerTask tasknew = new TimerTask() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("count : "+ count);
            count = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < 2100; i++) {
                count = count + 1;
                String ip = "192.168.2." + rnd.nextInt(255);
                String msg = " testing ";
                KeyedMessage<String, String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String>("Games", ip , msg);
                producer.send(data);

            }
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(tasknew, 100, 3000);
```

So what basically this does is to print 700 messages, every three seconds. I need the same to be done when I'm consuming as well. But to show the number of messages that have been consumed within a period of 3 seconds for example.

How can I work it around? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I would say **YES**. 
Yes we can do monitor the consumer and find it out what is the message rate of consumers. 
To have this there are multiple tools available like - [KAFKA UI](http://www.kafkatool.com/) and [GANGLIA](http://crazyadmins.com/kafka-integration-with-ganglia/). 
KAFKA provides **JMX** port which is configurable when we install these tools and you can simply see the metrics.